# Running a capistrano command from within a GLI command fails

Tags: ruby, command-line, gli-gem

I am using [GLI](http://davetron5000.github.io/gli/) to create a command suite application.

I have the following command (simplified):

```
command :my_command do |c|
  c.action do |global_options,options,args|

        Dir.chdir '../wordpress'
        system("cap -T")
        Dir.chdir '..'

  end
end
```

Any other command `ls`, `git pull`, whatever, works fine, but when I try to run `cap` I get this error:

```
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:214:in `block in replace_gem': capistrano is notpart of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/cap:22:in `<main>'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Running the `cap` command manually in the `../wordpress` folder works fine.

Comment: you could try this: `Bundler.with_clean_env`

Comment: @phoet Simple as that - thank you. Do you want to put that in the form of an answer so I can accept?